# R Sentiment Analysis with syuzhet tm corpus

Tags: text-mining, sentiment-analysis, tm

I'm newbie to text analysis in R, is there an easy way to apply the syuzhet: get_nrc_sentiment to a corpus with x elements (loaded individual text files)? I'm guessing you need turn the corpus back to a combined plain text file and use that?

s<-get_nrc_sentiment(.....)

thanks

Comment: you might want to read [tidytext mining with r](https://www.tidytextmining.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: use unlist on the corpus, e.g.  data.frame(text=unlist(sapply(a, `[`)), stringsAsFactors=F) then get_nrc_sentiment on the text column of that dataframe